# How to get coordinates of recognized characters

Tags: tesseract

I have a very simple OCR app based on Tesseract. After the recognition
step, I also provide a user verification step that allows correction
in case OCR is wrong. To improve the user interface, I plan to draw a
rectangle on top of the OCR-ed character on the original input image,
and put it side by side with the OCR output. To get to that, I need
the coordinate of the recognized characters.

I tried something like this but it seems to give me gibberish:

```
   ETEXT_DESC output;
   tess->Recognize(&output);
   text = tess->GetUTF8Text();
```

Now if I access output->count, it gives me some value above 10,000,
which is obviously wrong because the whole image only has 20 or so characters.

Am I on the right track? Can I have some direction please?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's helpful to get the coordinates of the boxes.
Try the executable of tesseract. Use the command

> "tesseract.exe [image] [output] makebox"

Afterall you get the coordinates of each character, one per row. Then you are able to compare.

Answer (score 1):

The `tesseract` executable has an option *hocr* to output recognized characters and their coordiantes in *html* format. To get this programmatically, the [FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ) says to refer to `baseapi.h`.